# Configuring Host Only Network for Debian Buster 64-bit VirtualBox Guest on Gentoo Linux

Tags: debian, virtualbox, network-interface

I am trying to install Debian Buster 64-bit as VirtualBox Guest.

The host is Gentoo Linux.

When I went to Host Network Manager, I saw that the default IP address was set to 192.168.56.1.

Without changing it, I tried to run the installer and it failed to automatically configure the network interface, but even trying to set it up manually fails, because the address should be a `broadcast` one - not an IP address.

So what is the proper way to set up VB + Debian with the Host Only Network?

Comment: what makes you think *the address should be a broadcast one - not an IP address* - that makes no sense. Have you ever seen a network interface with only a broadcast address?

Comment: This is all so wrong. And with "Host Only" you have no Internet connection for your guest but DHCP will work regardless.

Comment: @JaromandaX, not sire what you mean. Addresses that have 1 at the end are broadcast ones. Look at the output of your ifconfig/ipconfig...

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, so what settings should vm have? BTW, all I need is DHCP...

Comment: DHCP is enabled by default for NAT and Host Only modes. If it doesn't work for your guest, it's your guest issue, not an application issue. I've been using VBox for over 15 years now and I've had zero issues with DHCP with multiple guests including Windows 95, NT 3.51, QNX, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc. etc. etc. Maybe your Debian guest doesn't support the chosen network adapter.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I know DHCP is working fine. Problem is - for some reason the installer doesn't recognize the VM card and fails to set up the network. I will see if I can get any suggestions from Debian people.